# str_replace() removes numeric value with / in a string?

Tags: php, string

My code:

```
<?php

    $string="img\1\EVS\Good Habits.mp41.png";
    echo str_replace('\\','/',$string);

?>
```

Output:

```
img/EVS/Good Habits.mp41.png
```

My original string was : `img\1\EVS\Good Habits.mp41.png`, but in output it removed `1`.

Please tell me the reason if anyone know this ?

Comment: `\1` inside your double quotes is "interpreted" as chr(1) rather than a literal `\1`. Either single quote your $string (`$string='img\1\EVS\Good Habits.mp41.png';`) or escape the slash (`$string="img\\1\EVS\Good Habits.mp41.png";`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the fault from `str_replace()`. If you do:

```
echo $string;
```

you will already see that you lost the number there:

```
img\EVS\Good Habits.mp41.png
```

Because your backslash escapes the 1. So the solution?

You have to escape your backslashes in your original string OR change your double quotes to single quotes, so that the [`escape sequence`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) doesn't get interpreted from PHP anymore.

Comment: what if the $string=$_POST['string'] ?

Comment: @Shelim What do you mean with `$string=$_POST['string']` ? If the string comes from there?

Comment: Yes. the string value comes from form post.Then how to make this single quoted or any escape sequence just \1 part of the string.

Comment: @Shelim If it just comes from a plain text input you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what the plain text input mean ? To my case the string is the form post value.

Comment: @Shelim Just like: `<input type="text" name="xy">` If your input comes from there it should work all fine